# How do I use mobile control 8051 in C

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, 8051

I need to use my mobile controlled LED with AT89S51.
I'm using Bluetooth (HC-05) and PNP(9012).
my mobile program form App Inventor, this app can control bluetooth car.
but mobile can't control LED, LED Loop is ok ,this problem is still puzzling me.
I search some information for AT89S51 Uart.

that's program code on the internet.
[enter link description here](http://chopapp.com/#mqpwcr56)

that's my program code.
[enter link description here](http://chopapp.com/#b4f4cowi)

someone can guide about use 8051 uart ?

Comment: Please include the relevant minimal code example directly in your question, rather than linking off site.

Comment: I can't complete the paste,sorry man.